# SQL Query with two WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

My task is:
To make a query which will get Employees, who earn the biggest salary for their working experience. In other words, the Employee who earns the biggest salary with the biggest experience.

As I consider, I need to make a query with two conditions:

```
select * from employee where salary in (select max(salary) from employee) and 
hire_date in (select min(hire_date) from employee)
```

[image: DB Structure]

Comment: The requirement isn't clear to me. Could you share some sample data and the result you want to get for that sample? It will help clarifying things.

Comment: (1) is there a column somewhere that gives the measurement of `experience` ? (2) `Employee who earns the biggest salary with the biggest experience.` What if the employee with biggest salary has the lowest experience ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this was what you're trying to do:

```
    select * from (
    select *,
    datediff(day,hire_date,getdate()) [Days_Worked],
    dense_Rank() over(Partition by datediff(day,hire_date,getdate()) order by salary desc) [RN]

    from employee 
    )a
    where a.RN = 1
order by Days_Worked DESC
```

So that'll give you a list of employees with the highest salary against the employees that have worked the same number of days.

Just note that with dense rank if for example there are 2 employees that have worked 88 days and both earn $50000 (higher than anyone else) it will list both employees, use ROW_NUMBER() instead of DENSE_RANK() if you want to restrict examples like that to 1 employee.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly, this query solves your problem.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * FROM 
    employee 
ORDER BY
  hire_date ASC,
  salary DESC
```